# Remove/exclude enum cases in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

This is a struct that contains the operations enabled in the game:

```
struct OperationsEnabled {
    var addition = 1
    var subtraction = 0 // disabled
    var multiplication = 1
    var division = 1
}
```

This is the enum I use to generate simple arithmetic questions:

```
enum BinaryOperation: String {
    case Addition = "+"
    case Subtraction = "-"
    case Multiplication = "×"
    case Division = "÷"

    func rangesForDifficulty(difficulty: Difficulty) -> (Range<Int>, Range<Int>) {
        switch self {
        case .Addition:
            switch difficulty {
            case .Easy: return (1...10, 1...10)
            case .Intermediate: return (10...100, 1...100)
            case .Difficult: return (109...999, 109...999)
            }
        case .Subtraction:
            switch difficulty {
            case .Easy: return (1...10, 1...10)
            case .Intermediate: return (10...100, 1...100)
            case .Difficult:  return (109...999, 109...999)
            }
        case .Multiplication:
            switch difficulty {
            case .Easy: return (1...10, 2...4)
            case .Intermediate: return (1...50, 3...7)
            case .Difficult: return (10...100, 4...15)
            }
        case .Division:
            switch difficulty {
            case .Easy: return (1...10, 2...4)
            case .Intermediate: return (1...50, 3...7)
            case .Difficult: return (10...100, 4...15)
            }
        }
    }

    func apply(number1: Int, _ number2: Int) -> Int {
        switch self {
        case .Addition:
            return number1 + number2
        case .Subtraction:
            return number1 - number2
        case .Multiplication:
            return number1 * number2
        case .Division:
            return number1 / number2
        }
    }
}

// Let's make a new question
func newQuestion() {
    let (range1, range2) = binaryOperation.rangesForDifficulty(difficulty)
    let number1 = Int.random(range1)
    let number2 = Int.random(range2)
    let answer = binaryOperation.apply(number1, number2)
}
```

I want to filter out the operations. For example, I need to exclude the operations not allowed in the game, but there seems to be no way to use conditionals in here. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean exclude it from a switch statement?

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but note that your "random question generator" can generate divisions which do not have an integer answer, such as 10/3.

Comment: @MartinR Fixing it asap.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you added the [objective-c] tag? This question seems to be Swift-only.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Since I'm not interested in any language-specific code in the answers, I thought it'd be a good idea to include that tag. Removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to choose a random operation from the available operations.  Create an initializer for `BinaryOperation` that takes `OperationsEnabled` and creates a `BinaryOperation`.

```
init?(enabled: OperationsEnabled) {
    let all: [(BinaryOperation, Int)] = [(.Addition, enabled.addition), (.Subtraction, enabled.subtraction),
             (.Multiplication, enabled.multiplication), (.Division, enabled.division)]
    let avail = all.flatMap { (op, on) in on == 1 ? op : nil }
    if avail.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }
    else {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(avail.count)))
        self = avail[index]
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
let enabled = OperationsEnabled(addition: 1, subtraction: 1, multiplication: 0, division: 0)
let binaryOperation = BinaryOperation(enabled: enabled)!
```

#### Notes:

1. This works by first creating a paired list of tuples that contain an operation paired with its availability.
2. `flatMap` is used to select just those operations that are available.
3. If none of the operations were marked as available, then `avail` will be empty and this *failable* initializer will return `nil`.
4. The operation is chosen randomly from the list of available operations.

Answer (score 1):

Switch statements need to be "exhaustive" I.e. Cover all possible cases/enums. So your best bet is to either just use `if`s or use the `default` case, which will satisfy any case that you didn't explicitly define yourself (in this case the ones you want to 'filter')